# Clone existing G Suite account into the same organization

Tags: account-management, google-workspace-for-business, g-suite-administrator

Is it possible to clone a G Suite account from one domain to the same domain? I need to preserve a full copy at a given point of one account (including emails, Google Docs, calendar, etc.) that I can access in the future.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK G Suite doesn't include a built-in feature to "clone" G Suite accounts but you could use the export organization's data and transfer features to make a copy of several account files and data. For details see

- [Export your organization's data](https://support.google.com/a/answer/100458?hl=en)
- [Transfer data between G Suite accounts](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1041297?hl=en)

Note: There is a service called [Vault](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2462365?hl=en) that:

> ... lets you retain, hold, search, and export data to support your
>   organization’s archiving and eDiscovery needs

but it doesn't include all the account data.